# Cooling fan noise when head is moving in the X axis

Tags: diy-3d-printer, cooling, mechanics, print-fan

I have this [fan model](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/mf50151vx-a99/dc12v-fans/sunon/mf50151vx-b00u-a99/), it is a SUNON model number [MF50151VX-B00U-A99](https://www.tme.eu/en/Document/b30ea71fee61d11101012e50df6ac0ad/MF50151VX-A99-DTE.pdf)
and it is a blower type.

[image]

When the head is moving in the X-axis it makes noise.
I think this type of fans is not suitable for rapid movement and rapid changes in directions.

I think the noise is coming from the axial of the fan because I think there is a clearance in the axial for moving up and down.

When I put my finger on the fan body(the rotating part) the noise stop!

**My question, What type of fans suitable for rapid movement and rapid direction change? and if this is not the problem what is the problem in my situation?**

I have tried searching but I can really find a direct answer!

Comment: Julging from the picture, I'd guess the very small area where the blower is attached to the head may play a role, as it let it free to vibrate and resonate.

Comment: I have realized this just after wrote my questions but still not sure about it, I think this fan is not suitable for rapid movement changes!

Comment: well you said the noise stops when you put the finger on the _rotating_ part (so, I guess stopping the fan), but what happens if you put the finger on the case (so, the fiked part of the blower)?  if the noise stops or decrease dramatically, there you have it: the problem it's not the fan but the way is mounted on the printing head. :)

Comment: I did that and it is not making any noises, good observation, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments...

The problem with the fan seems to be its flimsy attachment to the printer head.  The fact the fan chassis is not firmly kept in place allows for it to act as a soundboard, amplyfing whatever vibration nomally occurs in the motor.

You could probably get a fan that is more silent in the first place ([noctua](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan) is a known brand for silent fans, and it is used on the Original Prusa MK3 for example), but since there's nothing inherently wrong with your current fan, I would simply design a custom, more beefy mount for it.  For added dampening effect you could also use small o-rings as washers for the screws.

Answer (score 4):

MagLev fans with Vapo bearing are (like the name suggests) magnetic levitation bearings - the rotor "floats" in the air, it's not press-fot like in ball bearings, therefore it has movement in perpendicular to the axis.

MagLev fans are great at low acceleration and low jerk (or in stationary applications) but their bearings will bang on sudden movement changes. Just take a MagLev (with Vapo bearing - VX, V1, V2..), there actually are Dual Ball Bearing versions of MagLev fans (BX, B1, B2..) which are way better suited in moving applications.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the answer from mac above. The Sunon Maglev Fan is actually an exceptional fan that is superior in all aspects: static pressure, CFM, Decibels et cetera. Far superior to that of a radial fan like a Noctua.

[Sunon - DC Brushless Fan & Blower](https://web.archive.org/web/20191124233417/http://www.sunon.com/index2/uFiles/file/03_products/08-catalog%20download/Sunon%20DC%20Brushless%20Fan%20&%20Blower_(240-A).pdf)

The noise probably comes from the way it's been attached to the printer.